# how to do the required field file upload validation with a anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, validation, upload, field, required

I'm doing the client side validation for the file upload field with jquery with a anchor tag. But the the form is getting submitted before getting validated or may be i missing something..can any one help me with this?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 banner-imageicon">
            <img src="/static/images/data.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 banner-info">
            <p class="big-text"> Excel Data Consolidation for Format 7</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h2 align="center">Below are the fields which will be added in the consolidates format:</h2>
        <p align ="center">Port of Loading (POL) and Origin City</p>
        <p align="center">Port of Destination and Destination City</p>
        <p align="center">Effective Date</p>
        <p align="center">Freight Charges</p>
        <p align="center">Expiry Date</p>
        <p align="center">Surcharges Not Subject to</p>
        <p align="right" class="Note">Note: By default commodity field is filled with the value-MSCUFAKOO1.</p>

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="frm" name="frm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p align="center"><h3>Choose the file whose data has to be consolidated</h3></p>

            <label for="file-upload" align="center">Browse....</label>
            <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file" style="display:none;"  align="center" required>
            <div id="file-upload-filename"></div>

            <div class="button">
                <a class="btn btn-first" href="#" id="submit"  onclick="document.getElementById('frm').submit()">Submit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-second" href="" onclick="document.getElementById('frm').reset()">Reset</a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/additional-methods.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("from function")
                $("#frm").validate({
                    ignore:[],
                    rules:{
                        file:{
                            required:true,
                        }
                    },
                    messages:{
                        file:{
                            required:"Please select the file"
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                    }
                });
                $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("from submit");
                    $("#frm").submit();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            var input = document.getElementById( 'file-upload' );
            var infoArea = document.getElementById( 'file-upload-filename' );

            input.addEventListener( 'change', showFileName );

            function showFileName( event ) {
                var input = event.srcElement;
                var fileName = input.files[0].name;

                infoArea.textContent = 'File name: ' + fileName;
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I want the validation message to be displayed if the form submitted before selecting the file. But the validation is not working.

Comment: What is `validate`? what library you're using? Also please indent your code properly it will help you and everyone else that's reading your code. See Wikipedia article: [Indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style)

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the reply..I will check into the indentation. the validate is used from Valid.js   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: Maybe it don't validate your input because it's hidden. Try `opacity: 0`, or container with width/height: 0 and overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the "classic" onsubmit attribute in the html part.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="myFunction()">
   Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

The other way would be to write a custom function which reads out the form and do the checking after reading the values. Then you also has to perform the send request on your own. Benefit: this can now also be done by ajax or a worker task. And for sure you can get rid of some sloppy coded html form construct issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Now i got the validation working just by adding the below   
               submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();


            }                                                                                                                                         but the validation message is appearing on the screen still i press the submit button.

Comment: the alert("The form was submitted"); was just added  that you can see that something is going on. Such a alert should only be shown if something is wrong with the form :) Or if you want to make the user happy. Alerts can not be removed from behind if created. The user has to click them. For simple dialogs or messages use just a DIV with some text. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp